Baking hair cards onto a plane
I wanted to bake some eyebrow cards onto a plane, and i'm having some issues with transparency. Eyebrows mesh i'm baking from is relatively high poly, but it's still made of cards, it uses a texture with transparent pixels. Here's how they look in the viewport:

And when i try to bake them onto a plane, here's the result i get (showing the alpha channel):

It seems like once the renderer encounters a transparent fragment on the eyebrow card, it bakes it as such, not considering the possibility that there could also be something opaque behind it. Does anyone know what can i do to make it bake properly, with everything that is supposed to be visible in the viewport?

Baking: Geometry behind transparent materials is ignored #119610
